# How to handle explode the get parameter and check it just like PHP in Python Google App Engine

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

After 1 complete day, I figured out a way to get the GET parameters in a python file.

Now on my URL `localhost:8080/test_file?mood=good,bad`, I want to explode a GET parameter just like we do in PHP with `explode(',', $_GET['mood'])`

In python I wrote:

```
mymood = cgi.escape(self.request.get('mood'))
```

Where I get `good,bad` on command `self.response.out.write(mymood)`
But when I use the .split function, then I am confused now, how to use decision statements like if else in this. (Actually I want to use like **in_array** in PHP - i.e. if `good` is there in the `mymood` python variable)
I wrote:

```
splitted = mymood.split(',')
```

and, it gives `[u'good', u'bad']` on command `self.response.out.write(splitted)`

How can I handle explode the get parameter and check it by using if else or in_array (just like PHP) in Python Google App Engine?

Comment: I want something like **if(in_array('good', mymood))**

Comment: for mood in mymood:
    if mood == 'good': etc...

Comment: I think you should read a python introduction somehwere (the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is pretty good) or you will keep stumbling into problems that are easily resolved by knowing the basic language syntax (like in this case, the `in` operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
if 'good' in splitted:
```

It is the equivalent of the PHP

```
if (in_array('good', splitted)) {
```